# I have a NoMethodError in one of my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just added a new comment feature to my rails app and stumbled upon this issue. I'm getting a NoMethodError in Pics#show which comes from my _comment.html.haml partial.

I can see the comment thread on my show page but after I post the comment I'm getting this. Can go back to uncommented pics, but can't go to the ones I've already commented on.

I've been staring at the code for a while now and I need a fresh pair of eyes.

```
Started GET "/pics/14" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-19 23:44:51 +0000
(0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM       "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
↳ /Users/alexfurtuna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by PicsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"14"}
Pic Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "pics".* FROM "pics" WHERE "pics"."id" = $1  LIMIT $2  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/pics_controller.rb:53
CACHE Pic Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "pics".* FROM "pics" WHERE "pics"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/pics_controller.rb:9
Rendering pics/show.html.haml within layouts/application
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/views/pics/show.html.haml:14
(0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3  [["votable_id", 14], ["votable_type", "Pic"], ["vote_flag", true]]
↳ app/views/pics/show.html.haml:20
Comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2  [["commentable_id", 14], ["commentable_type", "Pic"]]
↳ app/views/pics/show.html.haml:28
Rendered collection of comments/_comment.html.haml [1 times] (153.0ms)
Rendered pics/show.html.haml within layouts/application (220.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 267ms (ActiveRecord: 13.0ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method  `comment_comments_path' for #<#.  <Class:0x007fa535ee08b8>:0x007fa535ee9d50>
Did you mean?  pic_comment_comments_path):
2:   = comment.body
3:   %small
4:     Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago
5:   = form_for [comment, Comment.new] do |f|
6:     = f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Add a Reply"
7:     %br/
8:     = f.submit "Reply"

app/views/comments/_comment.html.haml:5:in    `_app_views_comments__comment_html_haml___2866288612795974586_70173756400620'
app/views/pics/show.html.haml:28:in `_app_views_pics_show_html_haml___2738689311384334047_70173775563600'
```

And this is my _comment partial.

```
%li
 = comment.body
%small
Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago
 = form_for [comment, Comment.new] do |f|
 = f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Add a Reply"
%br/
 = f.submit "Reply"
%ul
 = render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: comment.comments
```

Comment: What is the route for Comment create action?

Comment: per @MarkMerritt :   [comment, Comment.new] this is making the path for your form comment_comments_path. Try `[@pic, comment, Comment.new]` or `[@pic, Comment.new]` if you have a `@pic` instance variable defined. or you can add the route explicitly instead of building it from objects.

Can you also show us your route file?

Comment: @Tom your solution with the pic,comment, Comment.new worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @mehedi the issue is fixed now. thanks

Comment: @MarkMerritt it's all working now. thanks a lot tho

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fixed now and working properly. Had to pass the @pic variable. Thanks